# Showing undefined variable when passing url variable in php

Tags: php

I have two php pages and I want to pass variable value using URL while click on a hyperlink.

**Code snip 1: movie1-rev01.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Find my Favorite Movie!</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<a href='moviesite-rev03.php?favmovie=Stripes'>Click here to see movie</a>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code snip 2: moviesite-rev03.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Movie Site - <?php echo $favmovie; ?>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "My favorite movie is ";
echo $favmovie;
echo "<br>";
$movierate = 5;
echo "My movie rating for this movie is: ";
echo $movierate;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the link on page movie1-rev01.php then it shows an error message "Undefined variable: favmovie in C:\wamp\www\solutions\moviesite-rev03.php"

Please help me out. I'm new in PHP.

Comment: Use `$_GET['favmovie']`.

Comment: Use `isset($_GET['favmovie']) ? $_GET['favmovie'] : ''`.

Comment: @SomadderAbhijit if someone did helped you on this question, maybe you could repay them an upvote atleast or accept an answer

Comment: Okay. I'll do the same. But how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same by

```
$_REQUEST['favmovie'] or $_GET['favmovie']
```

ie.

```
define some variable,
$va = $_REQUEST[''favmovie];
instead of  echo $favmovie;
```

Comment: @ankit format your code properly so that code is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a `GET` variable in the second file.
Its not defined as `$favmovie` but `$_GET['favmovie']`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the get value to `$favmovie;`

Put

```
$favmovie = $_GET['favmovie'];
```

or

```
$favmovie = $_REQUEST['favmovie'];
```

at the top of the page or anywhere before using `$favmovie`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$_GET` to fetch the url variables.

So, in your `moviesite-rev03.php`. Do like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
   $favmovie = $_GET['favmovie'];
?>
<title>My Movie Site - <?php echo $favmovie; ?>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "My favorite movie is ";
echo $favmovie;
echo "<br>";
$movierate = 5;
echo "My movie rating for this movie is: ";
echo $movierate;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, for a side note: If you are planning to use this variable for database query purpose, I suggest to you to look into [removing sql injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 0):

First need to get variables that exists in url..
for that PHP provides several methods. In your case you can use GET.

you can use like this :

```
$favmovie = $_GET['favmovie'];
```

this will store value from variable(favmovie) in url and store it to **$favmovie** in that page..
now you can use $favmovie as you wish.

to display in page. use `echo $favmovie;` or  `echo $_GET['favmovie'];`

for more info:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php